How to use HP Computer Hardware for Linux to diagnose mouse trackpad and laptop issues?
I have bought a HP Pavilion Laptop PC 15-eg2000 (4U8D6AV), product number is  6T490UA, and the serial number is 5CD309DT78.
I had it since March 2023 of last year. I have installed Linux onto my laptop cause my husband said that it was a very good operating system to have. I have been having problems with the mouse trackpad where it sometimes works and then all of a sudden it stops working like I cant click on anything or move the mouse.
Also I had a problem with my computer but it's not a problem anymore. I was told by HP that I had to run a test called HP Computer Hardware from Linux. I have checked to see if my computer was still under warranty and it’s not.
I don't know how to do a HP computer Hardware from Linux test can you help me or tell me what options do I have in order to fix my problem?

Are you running Linux on the computer? Who told you that you are supposed to run this test? Can you give some details regarding the issues the mousepad is having? What sorts of "glitches" are you observing? Please EDIT your post to add this and other information that may be helpful.

Probably still in warranty. If so please contact your customer support and follow THEIR instructions.
